# check the exit code inside a if statement before existing script

Tags: bash

I want to check the exit code of the second condition before existing the script

```
if [ -f "/var/lock/myproc/agentlock" ] && \
   [ $(ps ax | grep "myproc" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9) ]; then

 echo "Exiting without running the rest of the script" | sendmail $myemail
 exit

fi
```

I want to `exit` the script if the exit status of the second command is non-zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
sendmail $myemail || exit # will exit if sendmail exit status is non-zero
```

Most probably you want to quote `$myemail` like so: `sendmail "$myemail"`. This will prevent bash globbing from screwing your emails.

As you can see, you can use `&&` to check for zero exit codes and `||` for non-zero.

Also you can write short if statements using `&&` `||` trick:

```
[[ 'hello' == 'world' ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

If you want to negate a condition, use `!`
Like this:

```
if [ firstcondition ] && ! [ secondcondition ]; then
```

which means '' If first condition is true AND second condition is NOT true ''

Comment: No, this isn't what I am looking for. This will still send the email if the file is there and the exit status of the second condition is zero.

Comment: Oh! So you want to negate the second condition, right? Just place the ! before the second condition. Like this ``! [ ]``